# make search in excel files faster

Tags: c#, .net, excel, search

i have a c# .net application that read and write from excel files. my search compare data from 20 cells in each file, so searching in 10000 files tkes 70 seconds which is very long !! any ideas of a better solution to make it faster.
here is the read function:

```
 public static void OpenExcel(string fileName, bool visibility, FunctionToExecute fn = null)
    {
        string addInPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Microsoft\\AddIns\\mDF_XLcalendar.xla");

        deleg = fn;
        app = new Excel.Application();

        app.Workbooks.Open(addInPath);
        app.Workbooks.Open(fileName);

        app.ScreenUpdating = true;
        app.DisplayAlerts = true;
        app.Visible = visibility;
        app.UserControl = true;
        app.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMaximized;

        EventDel_BeforeBookClose = new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeCloseEventHandler(application_WorkbookBeforeClose);
        EventSave_BeforeBookClose = new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeSaveEventHandler(Open_ExcelApp_WorkbookBeforeSave);

        app.WorkbookBeforeClose += EventDel_BeforeBookClose;
        app.WorkbookBeforeSave += EventSave_BeforeBookClose;

    }
```

and here is the code that do the search:

```
string searchString = ((RichTextBox)searchObject.LstObject[0]).Text.Trim();

            bool contain = ExcelFunctions
                                .RemoveDiacritics(ExcelFunctions.Read(GetSummaryXl, coord))
                                .ToLower()
                                .Contains(ExcelFunctions.RemoveDiacritics(searchString).ToLower());

            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) && contain);
```

i did many tests and it seems that my read function takes 90% of the search time in one file.

Comment: I don't know whether this is an option for you, but 10000 Excel files are rarely a good idea, especially when you have to do queries that range over all of them. Have you considered migrating your data to a proper database?

Comment: Consider that you're forcing the system to open/close 10,000 excel files, which amounts to running/quitting Excel 10,000 times. 70 seconds is actually pretty good, all things considered.

Comment: `i did many tests and it seems that my read function takes 90% of the search time in one file.` Do you mean in one particular file? can you search this one last?

Comment: I am frankly amazed that you can do this in 70 seconds.  And the only likely way to get it faster than that is to store the data somewhere that can be retrieved faster than the implicit overhead of 10,000 Excel files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd prefer Multi-Threading if I was you, it would use up a-lot of CPU for sure, but it's x times faster compared to a single thread.

[This](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_multithreading.htm) is a well explained Multi-Threading tutorial, easy to use too!

Comment: I don't think that would help, @John, each thread would still be going across the COM boundary.

Comment: when i tried the multi threading in my read function using 3 threads i won more 50% in performance (more than 3 dosen't change anything) so i'm working in this direction now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Guys, it's crazy !!! after applying 4 threads and building a small cache system on a dual core processor in my labtop, Searching in 3904 excel files and looking totally in 46848 cells, we're getting the result in .......... 0.5609 seconds !!!! can any one do better :))))

Comment: You'd be surprised what the power of a GPU can do ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you try to use the OLEDB driver instead of the Office.Interop.  It is much faster for reading data from excel.

For examples on how to connect to excel, check out [ConnectionString.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/)

Comment: No the client don't want a database so it's not an option.

Comment: This is NOT a database. This is a way to connect to the excel file like it is a database and read the data MUCH faster. You can perform queries as well. [Try this](https://www.google.com/#q=read+excel+file+through+oledb+in+c%23)

Answer (score 0):

The underlying reason you're suffering performance issues is that every read of a cell is a trip across the COM / .Net boundary, which is very expensive. If OLEDB doesn't suit, try reading all the data in one trip across the boundary; this can be done by returning a 2 dimensional array from a VBA macro and executing the macro via interop.

Another idea is to develop a COM add-in in C++ but that is far more complex.